# create custom report for ledger

Tags: python, odoo

I have a problem for days and I can not solve,

I want to make a ledger so I want to tell me the accounts that I have in my system and that in them separate the debit and credit where these fields are already specified as attributes but that before having a date filter so that according to the range of dates that one puts the movements are shown.

It is because of the above that I have the following code and method that I have tried to perform but the data does not appear in the report.

Another problem I have is that because the dates are placed in the `detail_movement` table as I explain below and not in the table it counts how to call that attribute so that it is shown in the method that I perform more at the end.

Then I leave a link on an image of the expected result:

`class detail_documen`t. Here is the date on which the account was moved.

```
class Document_Detail (models.Model):

  _name = 'project_rc.detalle_documento'

  date = fields.Date (string = "Date", default = lambda self: date.today (), required = True)

  account_id = fields.Many2one (asdel_name = 'project_rc.account', string = 'Account')
```

account table. In this is the name of the accounts and a computed attribute which adds all the debts and credits.

```
class Account (models.Model):

  _name = 'project_rc.account'

  title = fields.Char (string = "Name")

  total_account_debe = fields.Float (string = "Total account must", compute = "_ total_deccount_deb")

  total_cuenta_haber = fields.Float (string = "Total account have", compute = "_ total_cuenta_haber")
  document_document_ids = fields.One2many (as del_name = 'project_rc.detail_document', inverse_name = 'account_id', string = 'Document detail',
      required = True)
```

Now start the py to be able to make the report:

```
class Book (models.TransientModel):

_name = 'project_rc.book'

start_date = fields.Date (string = "Start date", required = True)

end_date = fields.Date (string = "End date", required = True)

@ api.multi

def get_report (self):

    data = {

        'ids': self.ids,

        'model': self._name,

        'form': {

            'date_start': self.date_start,

            'date_end': self.date_term,
        },

    }

    return self.env.ref ('project_rc.report_ledger'). report_action (self, data = data)
class Reportledger (models.AbstractModel):

_name = 'reports.proyecto_rc.ledger_view'

@api.model

def _get_report_values ​​(self, docids, data = None):

    start_date = data ['form'] ['start_date']

    end_date = data ['form'] ['end_date']

    docs = []

    accounts = self.env ['project_rc.account']. search ([], order = 'name asc')

    for account in accounts:

        items = [transaction.amt

                for transaction

                in self.env ['transaction']. search (

                    ('account', '=', account.id),

                    ('date', '> =', start_date.strftime (DATETIME_FORMAT)),

                    ('date', '<=', date_end.strftime (DATETIME_FORMAT))

        )]

        docs.append ({

            'account': id_count,

            'date': date,

            'must': total_account_deb,

            'to have': total_ccount_to have,

        })

    return {

        'doc_ids': data ['ids'],

        'doc_model': data ['model'],

        'start_date': start_date,

        'end_date': end_date,

        'docs': docs,

    }
```

I would be very grateful for your help, because I have been trying for several days.